# Order status only showing processing in Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

In magento2, when I go to fresh orders it shows Order Status as processing even after when I have generated the invoice and shipped the product it still showing order status processing, it should be automatically changed to Complete.

Everything is happening normally when I disable my payment gateway Extention (Paytm).

Comment: Any error description in log file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?